# How to sort data recieved in php into 3 different div tags in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-modal

Im using php to collect my instagram feed however all the images php collects using the instagram api are all placed in the same location(or same div) so i recieve my images

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
<div class="images">
<!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution,high_resolution)-->
<a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php endforeach ?> </div>
```

so all the images collected are turned into links and are all placed in the div images so what i would like to do is equally distribute all 20 images received into these 3 different divs using php or js.

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>,
<div class="col-md-4"></div>,
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

This is my first post, code might be awkward. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've gone ahead and built out a proper full solution.  It works by first building an array of response objects, then chunking them out for display.  If you want to split them up, you'll pretty definitely need to put them into a sub-buffer, like the `$results` buffer you see below.

```
<?php 
    $results = array();
    foreach ($result->data as $post): 
        // Using output buffering as a simple means of building HTML.
        ob_start();
?>
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>">
        <img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>">
    </a>
<?php
        $results[] = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    endforeach;

    // Now we have an array of elements as HTML.  We'll chunk them
    // into 3 arrays.  We could also randomize or other things here.
    $chunked = array_chunk($results, 3);
?>
<div class="col-md-4"><?=implode("\n", $chunked[0])?></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><?=implode("\n", $chunked[1])?></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><?=implode("\n", $chunked[2])?></div>
```

Comment: WOW AWEOME!!! exactly what I needed. But what if I wanted to have 6 divs to put 18 images 3 in each div, what would I have to change?

Comment: Set the `array_chunk` to 6, and the $chunked will index all the way to 6 items ($chunked[5]).

Comment: Thanks I was able to do it! @JohnGreen

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split your array and then iterate it within your desired div tag.

Example:

```
<?php
$chunked = array_chunk($array, 3);

foreach ($chunked as $value) {
    foreach($value as $v) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        print_r($v);
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the first part of your answer is correct enough... but the 2nd part is just clearly wrong on many levels.

Comment: @JohnGreen Please explain.

Comment: I need you to explain plz.

Comment: @toxicfelix it's simple. as you want to show the data in 3 divs/columns, I have divided/splitted the array having at least 3 items. then I have iterated through each array, and added them in the div/column.

Comment: hmm it somewhat works however that php code puts everysingle piece of information in different divs and prints out a lot of text and i only want the images to show for example a div is created for every hashtag used in an image and printed in the screen while without this code it only prints out the images. Any idea how i can only get the images to be separated, THanks alot!

Comment: If it helped please accept my answer and can you please show me what you are getting now with my code so that then ì can suggest what adjustment you need to make?

Comment: You chunk the array.  But you don't do anything with the chunk.  So that part of the code does absolutely nothing... Your addressing in the second part ($result->data) launches over the keys of $result->data instead of $result->data->images.  Since you had far enough with the array_chunk, I was justing giving you time to formulate a proper, full response.  : )

Comment: So for example all the $result I got from the instagram api is text so it is creating a div for every single line of text, like who liked it, the image title, the hashtags. What I was thinking is somehow put the image inside the print_r or use and echo so something like this.

Comment: `foreach ($result->data as $value) {
    foreach($value as $v) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
        echo '<a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>'
        echo '</div>';`

Comment: Heh.  I'd given up waiting and just written a more fleshed out version below.  : )

Comment: @JohnGreen that's great.

Comment: so basically the problem is that the print_r($v); is printing out all information and i only want to create a new div for the <a> elements showed in my html code any ideas?

Comment: @toxicfelix yeah. I have used print_r() as just an example to show you how we are getting the data.